# SE analytics breakdown needs clarification on google domains

Tags: support, moderator-tools, analytics

SE analytics include breakdowns of which search engines refer traffic. Are the country-specific google domains (e.g. google.co.in, google.ca) included in the generic 'Google' category?

They seem to also appear in the "referring sites" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google sends us both search traffic and referral traffic.

For search traffic, yes, all of the Google domains are counted together in the Google category.

We also see referral traffic from Google domains for things like Google Reader, gadgets from iGoogle, etc.

So, while you see the same name listed as both a referrer and search traffic, the sources and numbers are tracking different things there.